# finding a simple tutorial / explanation about the "choose a color" method to ask sensitive questions

Tags: bayesian, survey

I have a 'hard science' background and I remember in high school a lecture about how to ask sensitive questions to a group of people by using bayesian statistics and the "choose a color" trick. For example, "choose a color, either red or blue; answer yes if you either have thought blue, or if you are hiv positive".

I was shocked to hear that someone close to me, who has a sociology / psychology background, has not heard about this method. Do you know 1) if it has a dedicated name in the literature / handbooks in sociology / psychology, 2) if there are some simple tutorials / explanations of the method for people with little to no probability / statistics / maths background that I may refer this person to? I googled for this but could not find it. (I can build such an explanation myself but it would be a bit of work, as there is a true vulgarization work to do to explain this to somebody with a weak proba background :) ).

Comment: Could you clarify how does this relate to statistics?

Comment: Is it not statistics and probability forum? Or is there a separate forum for each of these?

Comment: Than how does this relate to probability theory?

Comment: And in a sense, this is a method to produce statistics over your population when the population is not willing to answer the question because it is too sensitive...

Comment: I think the core of the question is clearly about stats / probas applied to real-world problems. I agree that I am more asking for "do you know where I can find more about this", but is this really outside of the scope? If yes I can remove, but that would feel a bit sad.

Comment: From your question it is not clear what exactly is the problem you are talking about and how does this relate to probability theory.

Comment: @Tim The reason is that the OP doesn't remember the method with perfect accuracy: the color must be chosen with a specified probability, often by rolling a die or spinning a spinner.  It's useless to ask the respondent just to "choose" an option arbitrarily.  When done correctly, this is indeed an established survey technique for getting honest answers to sensitive questions and requires a probability analysis for its understanding.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_response.

Comment: Oh yes, this is the method / explanation I was looking for @whuber , many thanks :) I just did not know what to google for... :)

Comment: I found the Wikipedia article by Googling for ["survey+random+sensitive".](https://www.google.com/search?q=survey+random+sensitive)

Comment: @whuber do you want to write this in a short answer maybe? :) .